# MS Build Error with SQL Server CE 4 and EF

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, msbuild, sql-server-ce, silverlight-5.0

I just changed a simple SQL Server Express Datebase to SQL Server CE 4. This DB lives in the App_Data folder of an ASP.NET WebProject, which is also the host for my Silverlight project.

Then I build a EF-model based on this SSCE Database using Entity Framework 4.

And this model is the base for my WCF RIA Service.

Everything compiles and runs locally without problems. But I get an exception when trying to compile on our build server:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets (305): Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  MyModel.ssdl(2,91) : error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

From the log file it seems, that the exception happens in the Silverlight project - not in the Webproject.

Does anybody know what I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is SQL Server Compact 4.0 runtime installed on the build server?

Comment: SSCE needs a runtime installed?? From my understanding just a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe is needed.

Comment: No, either a MSI installed, or you must include a number of DLL files as content